# Flask-Security - Username to generate auth token instead of email

Tags: authentication, flask-security, flask-mongoengine

I am developing an application using Flask and using Flask-security for token based authentication feature. 
I developed a prototype code looking at docs and different examples I could find on internet. I see 'email' field is required to get a auth token. But I need 'username' field instead. 
I tried changing 'email' to 'username' attribute in the user model but it throws an error while requesting for the auth token - "Email not provided"

Is there some config flag that I am missing?

FYI, I am using MongoEngineUserDataStore

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SECURITY_USER_IDENTITY_ATTRIBUTES = ['username']`

From the [docs](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/24ed2725d76f45b1b00ce167b199750236d94189/docs/configuration.rst#miscellaneous) :

> Specifies which attributes of the user object can be used for login.
>   Defaults to ['email'].